# Consultar por fechas por un campo dentro de un array con múltiples objetos

Tags: mongodb

En una colección, tengo documentos como éste:

```
{
  "_id" : "ARJ05542",
  "name" : "aaaaa",
  "offers" : [{
      "product-sku" : "0698615096855",      
      "shop-id" : "2003",
      "date_modified" : ISODate("2016-11-29T09:31:42.891Z"),      
    }, {
      "product-sku" : "0698615096855",      
      "shop-id" : "2007",
      "date_modified" : ISODate("2016-12-06T15:15:22.242Z"),
    }]
}
```

Necesito una query que me permita obtener todos aquellos objetos dentro del array `offers`, cuya fecha de modificación esté entre dos fechas.

He tratado de conseguirlo mediante la siguiene consulta, pero no me devuelve resultados:

```
db.TL01_A.aggregate([

/* with offers*/
{"$match" : 
    {
        "offers" : {"$exists" : true}
    }
},
/*unwind by offers*/
{"$unwind" : "$offers"},

/* group by offers*/

{
    "$group" : 
        {
            "_id" : "$offers"
        }

},
/* sort */
{"$sort" : {"_id" : 1}},
/* modified between dates*/

{"$match" : 
    {

        "$and" : [
            {"date_modified" : {"$gte" : { "$date" : "2016-11-03T12:18:48.477Z"}}}, 

            {"date_modified" : {"$lt" : { "$date" : "2016-12-25T12:18:48.477Z"}}}]

    }
},


/* skip */
{"$skip" : 0},
/* limit */
{"$limit" : 50}
],
{allowDiskUse : true}
)
```

En el momento en el que pongo la consulta por fecha siempre me devuelve cero resultados.

Answer (score 4):

Las fechas están almacenadas en formato numérico. Sin embargo, el query lo estás realizando con un string. Deberías convertir la fecha a objeto con [`ISODate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date)

Dentro del query, la condición sería:

```
{
    "$match" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {
                "date_modified" : {
                    "$gte" : { 
                        "$date" : ISODate("2016-11-03T12:18:48.477Z")
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "date_modified" : {
                    "$lt" : {
                        "$date" : ISODate("2016-12-25T12:18:48.477Z")
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    } 
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Aquí un ejemplo más simple:

```
  {
    $match: {
      "date_modified": { $gt: ISODate("2018-08-01T15:21:27.625"), $lt:  ISODate("2018-08-31T15:21:27.625") }
    }
  }
```

MongoDB entiende esta sintaxis. Estoy en la version 3.4.2, y migraremos a 4.0.0, tampoco hay problemas. Mongo entiende una operación AND cuando pones una coma.

Puedes ver esta [pregunta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107015/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-mongo-queries) o la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) para más información.

Comment: Hola JohnQO, bienvenido a la comunidad y gracias por tu aporte. No añades el `$and` que ponen en la pregunta o en otra solución, ¿es opcional? Es decir, ¿se aplica automáticamente por defecto?

Comment: No hay problema, MongoDB entiende la sintaxis. Estoy en la version 3.4.2, y migraremos a 4.0.0, tampoco hay problemas. Mongo entiende una operación AND cuando poner una coma. 
Puedes ver:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107015/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-mongo-queries
O la documentaciòn:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: Genial. Gracias por la información :)